# GA360 property is not in the list of properties to associate with GSC

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console

I'm verified owner of GSC domain. Now I try to associate with this GSC a GA360 property/view of the same domain, where I have `read & analyze` access rights, .

After click on <kbd>Associate</kbd> in GSC backend the GA360 property is not appear on the list of properties available for association. `Read & analyze` rights however are working correct for me: I use this view since some time without any issue.

What can I do?

Google [said in this fresh doc](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2021/08/search-console-insights-faq), I would have correct access rights and everything should work - but it doesn't. However, in the linked document Google mentions, GSC association with GA4 isn't currently possible - but GA360 isn't GA4, right?

I found another one misguiding sentence in the documentation of Google:
at the beginning of the doc linked above Google means, access rights should be `Read & analyze`.
Shortly before Google links another documentation: [how to create an association](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9419894#zippy=%2Crequest-google-analytics-association). And there Google means, one should have an `edit` permission:

[image]

But, in my understanding, `edit` permission is something completely different, then `read & analyze`. The difference is clear on the page, where access rights can be requested:

[image]

On the left are my current rights, on the right - checked checkboxes to request edit rights.

Then, again: what can I do? Should I request additional edit access rights? Or is there completely no chance to associate GSC with GA360?

Comment: GA360 isn't Universal Analytics which is what you would usually associate with GSC.   Not sure if the association is possible.

Comment: Google means *only GA4* can't currently be associated with GSC...

Comment: I know that's not entirely true. Even if you have universal analytics you can't associate with a domain property in Google search console.. It only supports prefix properties.

Comment: Hm, I have prefix property (`https://www`) - it is very very old, at the time of creation there was no domain property.